# Docker-compose invalid bind mount spec "/rootfs:ro": invalid volume specification

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm following the installation steps from [dockprom](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) but getting this error:

ERROR: for cadvisor  Cannot create container for service cadvisor: invalid bind mount spec "/rootfs:ro": invalid volume specification: '/rootfs:ro'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I added environment variable "COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1" to docker-compose.yml but this doesn't help.

docker 17.03.1-ce-win5 (10743)
windows 10

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is your docker instance configured for linux or windows containers? Did you make any changes to the compose files?

Comment: The only change that I've made was add envaironment var.

  cadvisor:
    environment:
     - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In docker-compose.yml for cadvisor just replace

```
volumes:
  - /:/rootfs:ro
```

with

```
volumes:
  - c:\:/rootfs:ro
```

For me it works:

```
grafana is up-to-date
nodeexporter is up-to-date
alertmanager is up-to-date
prometheus is up-to-date
Creating cadvisor

C:\docker-playground\dockprom>
```